# ng-repeat custom filter on key value object updates view only 2 times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I created a custom filter which filters key/value pairs e.g:

```
module.controller('tabController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   var self = this;
   self.items =  {
       "a": "a",
       "b": "b",
       "c": "c"
   }
```

The filter:

```
module.filter('filterKeyValue', function () {

return function (items, input) {
    if (!input) return items;
    input = input.toLowerCase();

    let filtered = {};
    let reverse = false;
    if (input.startsWith('!')) {
        input = input.slice(1).trim();
        reverse = true;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, (value, key) => {
        let k = key.toLowerCase();
        let v = value.toLowerCase();
        let indexOfKey = k.indexOf(input);
        let indexOfValue = v.indexOf(input);

        if (!reverse) {
            if (indexOfKey >= 0 || indexOfValue >= 0) {
                filtered[key] = value;
            }
        } else {
            if (indexOfKey < 0 && indexOfValue < 0) {
                filtered[key] = value;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('filtered items: ', filtered);
    return filtered;
};
});
```

The filter works perfectly fine (always returning the correct filtered items according to console.log)

The problem lays in the view, the view gets updated with the filtered items only twice (always twice for some reason, or a 3th time if the search term does not exist in 'items')

```
So i search for:
'a' -> works fine, view gets updated ('a' exists in 'items')
'b' -> works fine, view gets updated ('b' exists in 'items')
'c' -> does not work, the view does not get updated ('c' exists in 'items')
'f' -> does work, view gets updated with no results ('f' does NOT exist in 'items')
```

I use the following markup (short version):

```
<div ng-controller="tabController as tab">

 <input type="text" ng-model="tab.filter">

 <table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Key</th>
           <th>Value</th>
        </tr>        
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in tab.items | filterKeyValue:tab.filter">
        <td>{{key}}</td>                                
        <td>{{value}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

It doesn't make sense to me that it works the first 2 times and after that it doesn't work anymore.

What could possibly be the problem here? This code runs in a chrome extension (popup.html) but i don't think it should matter.

Comment: do you have some fiddle . it works here http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32229/

Comment: @Rhea i see it works in fiddle indeed. That made me strip down my whole app. I think it comes due to a third party library. I need to figure out which one it is..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem:

**In my scenario, this problem was caused because i prototyped 'Object'.**
I haven't used the prototype in the filter. But by just having it in the code somewhere was causing this issue...